Did the U.S. government require SpaceX to study the impact of rocket launches on sharks and whales?
In the linked video Elon Musk mentioned that SpaceX was asked to research the impact of Starship launches on sharks and whales, among other bureaucratic work:

SpaceX had to do a study to see if Starship would hit a shark. I'm
like "It's a big ocean, there's a lot of sharks. It's not impossible,
but it's very unlikely."
...
Eventually we got the data, and the
sharks were going to be fine.
We thought we were done.
But then they hit us with: 'Well, what about whales?"
...
So then we had to do the whale analysis.

Is this claim true? I'm looking for proof of US government officials demanding such a study from SpaceX.

Yes, kind of
The claim is hyperbolic. An environment impact evaluation has been done where sharks and whales were included.
In FAA publication
Tiered Environmental Assessment for SpaceX Starship Indian Ocean Landings March 2024 "Environmental Assessment for SpaceX Starship Indian Ocean Landings"
It writes:

3.3.3.2 Listed Marine Species
At the request of the FAA, SpaceX conducted a literature review of ESA-listed endangered and threatened species with known or presumed distributions in the study area that may be affected by the proposed March 2024 13 FAA Office of Commercial Space Transportation Tiered Environmental Assessment for SpaceX Starship Indian Ocean Landings activities. Information sources included data obtained from NMFS endangered species web sites; experts in the occurrence and distribution of marine mammals, sea turtles, and fishes; and a review of available literature through established academic journals (ex., Public Library of Science (PLOS), Endangered
Species Research, Marine Mammal Science, etc.), and review of monthly new literature summaries provided by the Navy’s Marine Applied Research and Library Information Network (MARLIN). Focused distribution and conservation information for each species is included below. Table 1 summarizes ESA-listed species within the study area as well as their requisite habitat.

Emphasis added for clarity
Under 'Marine Mammals' (page 16-18) it lists whales. Sharks are listed page 15.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
